# multiarray - how to keep first 3 index groups of each source type

Tags: php

I have a multi-array where I need to keep the first 3 index groups and remove the rest from the multiarray (in each group).

See multiarray here: https://gist.github.com/no1uknow/6887497

So:
In this example I need the multi-array to keep: The first 3 Heavy, Lite, Intermediate, etc (these are identified by the source_type_cd)

Example of the Lite part of the array after the first 3 are kept:

```
 0 => 
    array (size=9)
      'validated_ata' => string '25' (length=2)
      'source_type_cd' => string 'Lite' (length=4)
      'validated_subata' => string '22' (length=2)
      'action_cd' => string '3' (length=1)
      'object_cd' => string '5' (length=1)
      'malfunction_cd' => string '29' (length=2)
      'corrective_action_txt' => string 'Repair-Passenger Seat-Loose / Displaced' (length=39)
      'rec_count' => string '00050' (length=5)
      'group_id' => int 48
  1 => 
    array (size=9)
      'validated_ata' => string '25' (length=2)
      'source_type_cd' => string 'Lite' (length=4)
      'validated_subata' => string '22' (length=2)
      'action_cd' => string '3' (length=1)
      'object_cd' => string '5' (length=1)
      'malfunction_cd' => string '1' (length=1)
      'corrective_action_txt' => string 'Repair-Passenger Seat-Inoperative' (length=33)
      'rec_count' => string '00047' (length=5)
      'group_id' => int 44
  2 => 
    array (size=9)
      'validated_ata' => string '25' (length=2)
      'source_type_cd' => string 'Lite' (length=4)
      'validated_subata' => string '22' (length=2)
      'action_cd' => string '3' (length=1)
      'object_cd' => string '5' (length=1)
      'malfunction_cd' => string '31' (length=2)
      'corrective_action_txt' => string 'Repair-Passenger Seat-Worn / Chaffed / Frayed' (length=45)
      'rec_count' => string '00042' (length=5)
      'group_id' => int 50
```

Answer (score 0):

You will simply have to loop through the array and look if it has any of those values and place into a new array.

Example (where `$arr` is your multiarray):

```
// My silly solution for knowing what to look for
// When one is found, it will be removed from the array.
$find = array('Lite','Lite','Lite','Intermediate','Intermediate','Intermediate','Heavy','Heavy','Heavy');

// New array where your the values you want will be placed in
$new_arr = array();

foreach($arr as $v) {
    // No need to keep looking if there's no more to find.
    if(empty($find))
        break;

    // Look in $find array if current "source_type_cd" is still sought-after
    $key = array_search($v['source_type_cd'], $find);
    if($key !== false) {
        $new_arr[] = $v;  // Add to new array
        unset($find[$key]); // Remove from "find" array
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Colandus I actually figured it out like this... I was trying to avoid to many loops.

In a loop above this I set the source_type_cd in an array:

```
$groups[]=$value['source_type_cd']
```

Next I loop through the array and take the top 3 of each group by using array_splice twice and then merging back into a new array.

(also, I'm using a start and end point ($group_count).)

```
$start = 0;
$group_count = $i+1;
$top_count = 3;

foreach($groups as $k => $v) {
    $top_count_array = array_merge((array)$top_count_array, (array)array_slice(array_slice($sorted_array, $start, $group_count, true),0,$top_count,true));
    $start = $start+$group_count;
}

var_dump($top_count_array);
```

Again appreciate the input. Tried to shorten this code down from so many loops. Also requirements will change for grabbing the amount of $top_count and $group_count... Needed something a little more dynamic. :-)